# How to show delta from start of timespan to point in time for counter

Tags: grafana

I am trying to visualize a counter increase over time.
But I'm facing two problems:

1. The graph doesn't start at zero for the timeframe and
2. When ever the counter resets, the graph hits zero again

This leads to the graph being very hard to read cause what I realy would like is to see how quickly the counter increases over time while being able to quickly get an overview of total amounts of increases at a given point in time measured from the start of the time frame.

[Visualisation of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86PEE.png)

**Update 20. November**

[Result of 'increase([your_metric_name][1m])'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWGnA.png)

Comment: What type of data source are you using (eg Prometheus, Graphite, InfluxDB, etc)? The specific aggregate functions you'll need to work with a counter will vary depending upon your data source.

Comment: I have Prometheus as datasource

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some type of rate or increase function to get the type of graph you're looking for. And since you're using Prometheus, your query will look something like this:

```
rate([your_metric_name][1m])
```

If you want the rate per second, OR

```
increase([your_metric_name][1m])
```

If you want something more like a delta.

These pages can give you more information too: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate()
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the question with the result which unfortunatly doesn't quite reach the target.